# Stop UAC/Secure Desktop from dimming the screen

Tags: windows-7, uac

I like the concepts of UAC and the "Secure Desktop" in Windows 7, but I don't like the dimming of the Secure Desktop to prompt for Admin credentials (or OK button to get clicked).

However, dimming goes so far that my monitor regularly goes into PowerSaver mode, which is annoying (as it takes another 10 seconds for it to wake up), and might harm the monitor: two weeks after switching from XP to Windows 7, my 30" monitor stayed black and it had to get replaced.

The web is full of tips how to turn off dimming, but that will always also turn off the "Secure Desktop".

Is there a way to present the Secure Desktop without dimming? Or with a different visual effect to show that it is the Secure Desktop?

*EDIT*: To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to disable dimming by disabling Secure Desktop (as is done by lowering the UAC level). I want to keep both UAC and Secure Desktop.

Comment: I think the reason the desktop is dimmed is to highlight the UAC box. While disabling UAC would work it's not the answer to your question. Have you looked into seeing if there is a regisrty key which defines the colour and density of the dim?

Comment: I've searched the web extensively and haven't found a way to keep UAC and "Secure Desktop" (SD) but not dim. Maybe you just cannot get SD without dimming?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, the thread is old, however, as I managed to find the solution for myself, I want to share it with everybody who like OP or me **wanted** UAC with Secure Desktop and ON but had problems of monitor/video modes switching. I'm on Windows 7 but I hope there's no difference to Vista for this solution to implement (can anybody try?).

The root cause of the problem (in my case at least) appeared to be slow switching to another video mode on Secure Desktop before dimming the screen. So, I looked for the way to find these settings somewhere then change them to more appropriate. As described here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-changes-screen-resolution-on-boot-up/13c17468-0d70-4827-a559-dca0fa558a69 the resolution and refresh settings are stored in multiple subkeys here:

**HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO**

so all I had to do is get my current user settings from Control Panel -> Desktop -> Adjust resolution (note Resolution parameters) and then -> Advanced settings -> Monitor (note Screen refresh rate parameter). These parameters could be entered by regedit in all subkeys having values **DefaultSettings.XResolution**, **DefaultSettings.YResolution** and **DefaultSettings.VRefresh**. Now Secure Desktop (check it by Ctrl+Alt+Del) doesn't switch to different mode, so that unacceptable UAC delay stopped to bother me. Hope it can help.

P.S. Another approach that worked **temporarily** was switching to Secure Desktop by Ctrl+Alt+Del, pressing accessibility button and checking **High Contrast** option. In my case it worked till first logout, so if the first approach won't work, try to investigate more in this alternative direction.

Comment: Van, Superuser is a knowledge base, not a forum. We *like* it when people come up with new answers to old questions.

Comment: This works! the UAC screen is dimmed, but it's so fast that the monitor will not go into sleep mode. Btw. my VRefresh setting was "1". I still changed it to 60, and it works.

Comment: @Florian, 60 is a good generic choice for all LCD monitors. For old non-LCDs, however, things are way more complicated and 60 would be one of the worst (though still workable) VRefresh choice. I just hope, for purpose of the solution, not that many non-LCDs left in possession as part of personal workstations suitable for Vista/7. ^_^

Comment: Yet another observation: my monitor still may be a bit "thinky" for the first time it switches modes since its power on. But after this first occurrence it's satisfactory fast as long as in power on state.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with _different resolutions_ when using 2 different monitors (LCD _and_ external, for example)?

Comment: I'd experiment with different subkeys representing different devices and having independent sets of resolution parameters

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO does not exist on Windows 10. A VIDEO key does exist in the same path beneath HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but it doesn't contain any DefaultSettings.xxx values.

Comment: I never checked it on Win10 since having this OS only on my laptop, thus not getting impacted by the original issue. I checked it today and still found this key there, though with somewhat insane values like DefaultSettings.XResolution=5040 or so. I decided not to alter it as already having enough DPI related inconsistencies in this OS. Of course, the reaction might be totally different as the original answer was given for long-ancient Win7, with which I'm still in love yet today. :-)

Comment: On my system the VIDEO key has only one subkey, which has a single 0000 subkey which has a single value: Attach.ToDesktop (set to "0"). I have multiple monitors. Should I just "blindly" add some values? Anyone succeeded solving this for multi-monitor setup?

Answer (score 16):

On Windows 7 search for "Change user account control settings" in the start menu and then move the slider to the position shown in the image. This will keep UAC enabled but won't dim the desktop.

[image]

Comment: I completely skipped over your answer because I looked at the slider, but not the text next to it.  Then I read the screen and was like *really*??!?  -1 to Microsoft for bad layout, but +1 to you for finding it!

Comment: wow, all the times I've just diabled UAC without realising that was there. +1 for you.

Comment: Do you know how to change this in Vista? It seems to only have full on and full off for UAC.

Comment: hi, sorry, this is not the right answer. Lowering UAC level to "not dim" mode will keep UAC, but will deactivate "Secure Desktop". The Secure Desktop prevents malware to spoof clicks, and to capture passwords.

Comment: @Dennis I don't think there is a way of doing this in Vista

Comment: @Florian: yes, that's true, but it's better than turning UAC off completely if you don't find any other solutions

Comment: @DennisWilliamson See my answer for a reg script. It works in Vista.

Comment: If you use [the registry change](http://superuser.com/a/361972/45163), then you have a different option: "**Always notify me (and do not dim my desktop) when:**", which satisfies [both conditions of the question](http://superuser.com/q/211875/45163).

Comment: @palswim No, because [it disables Secure Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232766.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use this registry script to turn off Secure Desktop:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:00000000
```

It is impossible to turn off dimming while keeping Secure Desktop. This is to keep users from asking „why doesn’t my desktop accept clicks?”.

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, this works perfectly. It doesn't require you to lower your UAC setting but keeps the idiotic screen flash from happening which plays havoc with my projectors.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, at least for Windows 10.

Comment: OP doesn't want to turn off Secure Desktop. -1

Comment: "I want to keep both UAC and Secure Desktop" said the OP. This "script" is just the registry counterpart of starofale's answer. Both of them (really the same) [disable Secure Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232766.aspx).