# UAC prompt window delays at least 1 minute in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uac, task-manager, delay

I have an issue with UAC, only when is executed for first time it delays at least one minute, after that, any task which requires it, the UAC promps in 2 or 3 seconds.

When I waiting that, I see in Task Manager a process named consent.exe, that's maybe the problem.

There's any way to solve this delay?

My system specs:

- AMD Phenom X3 8400 @2.1 GHz
- 2 GB DDR2 memory
- ATi Radeon HD4550 1 GB GDDR2 (I've read that could be graphics device)
- Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 32 bits

Comment: I saw this when a monitor is connected via DVI or HDMI, but no via VGA. It was fixed after updating the Video card driver.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yeah, my display is connected via DVI and I recently updated videocard drivers and is solved.

Comment: Just for anyone who stumbles on this page looking for a way to avoid delays when UAC is asking for confirmation to give administrator rights to a program, the solution is in another question: [Stop UAC/Secure Desktop from dimming the screen](https://superuser.com/a/512547/607984).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this when a monitor is connected via DVI or HDMI, but not via VGA. It was fixed after updating the Video card driver. So update your AMD graphic card driver.